# Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a firestore trigger. But I encountered an error

```
sendChatPushNotification
Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
    at Object.validateResourcePath (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/path.js:403:15)
    at CollectionReference.doc (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1988:20)
    at exports.sendChatPushNotification.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/workspace/index.js:38:8)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:132:23)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:198:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I got this error after update my dependencies. Now my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "9.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
```

And this is my cloud function

```
exports.sendChatPushNotification = functions.firestore
  .document("channels/{some_channel_document}/thread/{some_thread_document}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const data = change.after.data();
    const senderFirstName = data.senderFirstName;
    const content = data.content;
    const recipientID = data.recipientID;
    const url = data.url;

    let payload = {};

    if (url) {
      payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "Yeni Mesaj",
          body: `${senderFirstName} bir resim gönderdi`
        }
      };
    } else {
      payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "Yeni Mesaj",
          body: `${senderFirstName}: ${content}`
        }
      };
    }

    let pushToken = "";
    return firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(recipientID)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        pushToken = doc.data().pushToken;
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(pushToken, payload);
      });
  });
```

I tried different path like this ${some_channel_document} but the problem is not solved

Thanks for your help...

Comment: The error is telling you that the document path that you have assigned is getting null object. Try to print the document path and see what is there in document path.

Comment: Can you please share the entire code of your Cloud Function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I added

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the path on which you trigger the Cloud Function (i.e. `exports.sendChatPushNotification = functions.firestore
  .document("channels/{some_channel_document}/thread/{some_thread_document}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {})` is correct). Can you check the value of  `recipientID`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes you’re right. I solved the problem with your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help you! I've written an answer along these lines. Please accept and upvote it. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with the path on which you trigger the Cloud Function (i.e. `exports.sendChatPushNotification = functions.firestore   .document("channels/{some_channel_document}/thread/{some_thread_document}")   .onWrite((change, context) => {})` is correct).

The problem most probably comes from the other place where you declare a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) in your code, i.e.:

```
firestore.collection("users").doc(recipientID)...
```

You should check the value of `recipientID`.